# Nginx fastcgi getting 404 not found

Tags: nginx, fastcgi

My web root is /web/html/pub.  $MAGE_ROOT = /web/html

Here is sample of nginx conf.

```
root $MAGE_ROOT/pub;
index index.php;
autoindex off;
charset off;
location /pub {
    root $MAGE_ROOT;

    location ~ ^/pub/media/(downloadable|customer|import|theme_customization/.*\.xml) {
        deny all;
    }

    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
}
location ~ (index|info|get|static|report|404|503)\.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_pass   fastcgi_backend;
    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include        fastcgi_params;
}
```

Here is my debug error log.

```
2016/04/17 20:58:24 [debug] 4856#6680: *1 http script var: "html/magento202"
2016/04/17 20:58:24 [debug] 4856#6680: *1 open index "c:\web\nginx/html/magento202/pub/index.php"
2016/04/17 20:58:24 [debug] 4856#6680: *1 internal redirect: "/pub/index.php?"
2016/04/17 20:58:24 [debug] 4856#6680: *1 rewrite phase: 1
2016/04/17 20:58:24 [debug] 4856#6680: *1 http script value: "html/magento202"
2016/04/17 20:58:24 [debug] 4856#6680: *1 http script set $mage_root
2016/04/17 20:58:24 [debug] 4856#6680: *1 http script value: "developer"
2016/04/17 20:58:24 [debug] 4856#6680: *1 http script set $mage_mode
2016/04/17 20:58:24 [debug] 4856#6680: *1 test location: "/"
2016/04/17 20:58:24 [debug] 4856#6680: *1 test location: "setup"
2016/04/17 20:58:24 [debug] 4856#6680: *1 test location: "pub"
2016/04/17 20:58:24 [debug] 4856#6680: *1 test location: ~ "^/pub/media/(downloadable|customer|import|theme_customization/.*\.xml)"
2016/04/17 20:58:24 [debug] 4856#6680: *1 test location: ~ "(index|info|get|static|report|404|503)\.php$"
2016/04/17 20:58:24 [debug] 4856#6680: *1 using configuration "(index|info|get|static|report|404|503)\.php$"
2016/04/17 20:58:24 [debug] 4856#6680: *1 http cl:-1 max:1048576
2016/04/17 20:58:24 [debug] 4856#6680: *1 rewrite phase: 3
2016/04/17 20:58:24 [debug] 4856#6680: *1 post rewrite phase: 4
2016/04/17 20:58:24 [debug] 4856#6680: *1 generic phase: 5
2016/04/17 20:58:24 [debug] 4856#6680: *1 generic phase: 6
2016/04/17 20:58:24 [debug] 4856#6680: *1 generic phase: 7
2016/04/17 20:58:24 [debug] 4856#6680: *1 access phase: 8
2016/04/17 20:58:24 [debug] 4856#6680: *1 access phase: 9
2016/04/17 20:58:24 [debug] 4856#6680: *1 access phase: 10
2016/04/17 20:58:24 [debug] 4856#6680: *1 post access phase: 11
2016/04/17 20:58:24 [debug] 4856#6680: *1 try files phase: 12
2016/04/17 20:58:24 [debug] 4856#6680: *1 http script var: "html/magento202"
2016/04/17 20:58:24 [debug] 4856#6680: *1 http script copy: "/pub"
2016/04/17 20:58:24 [debug] 4856#6680: *1 http script var: "/pub/index.php"
2016/04/17 20:58:24 [debug] 4856#6680: *1 trying to use file: "/pub/index.php" "c:\web\nginx/html/magento202/pub/pub/index.php"
2016/04/17 20:58:24 [debug] 4856#6680: *1 trying to use file: "=404" "c:\web\nginx/html/magento202/pub=404"
2016/04/17 20:58:24 [debug] 4856#6680: *1 http finalize request: 404, "/pub/index.php?" a:1, c:2
2016/04/17 20:58:24 [debug] 4856#6680: *1 http special response: 404, "/pub/index.php?"
2016/04/17 20:58:24 [debug] 4856#6680: *1 http set discard body
2016/04/17 20:58:24 [debug] 4856#6680: *1 HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
```

For the life of me, i can't figure out why nginx inserts "pub" into the url twice when i try to go to http://domain/pub/.  Any ideas what i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Your `location /pub` attempts to resolve the URI `/pub/` by applying the inherited `index` directive and rewrites the URI to `/pub/index.php`.

Now, any URI ending in `.php` is processed by the `location ~ (index|info|get|static|report|404|503)\.php$` block.

Within this block, the (inherited) root is defined as `.../pub`, which is prefixed to the URI making: `.../pub/pub/index.php`

Comment: I had that sneaking suspicion.  Is there a way to fix the php catch block so the correct URI gets passed to cgi?